# Bcrypt compare always returning TRUE in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm making my own small API, and I've coded out the following POST request to my MongoDB database:

```
api.post("/account/login", async (req, res) => {

    const user = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    const username = JSON.stringify(user.username);

    const hashedPassword = await logincollection.find(user.username).toArray();
    const hardCodedPassword = "$2b$10$q0iOBFTqqZ3vnp5oqDQUqejdS7UD/ayw4Q4qgi5hs1pfFI.xfipDS"
    console.log(hashedPassword)

    // Search for matching login credentials
    logincollection.find(user, (err, result) => {

        try {

            if (bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, hardCodedPassword)) {
            
                // Return credentials back to the client
                const sendObject = {
                    username: result.username,
                    password: result.password
                };

                console.log(sendObject);
                    
                // Return code 200 (success) to the client
                res.status(200).send(sendObject);

                // Log to console when user logs in
                console.log("User " + username + " logged in");

            }

        } catch(error) {

            // If matching credentials were not found, return code 404 (wrong credentials) to the client
            res.status(404).send()

        }

    })

})
```

I have set a valid hardcoded password for purely testing purposes. When this request is processed, `console.log(sendObject)` prints undefined results to the console and bcrypt returns `true`, no matter what password I put in. What's the problem here?

Comment: Compare doesn't return a Boolean. It returns a _promise_, which is truth-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe said, `bcrypt.compare` returns a Promise not a value.  You must use a callback function, Promise.then() or async/await to handle the asynchronous result.

```
// Search for matching login credentials
logincollection.find(user, (err, result) => {

  bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, hardCodedPassword)
  .then(match => {      
    if (match) {
      // Return credentials back to the client
      const sendObject = {
          username: result.username,
          password: result.password
      };

      console.log(sendObject);
          
      // Return code 200 (success) to the client
      res.status(200).send(sendObject);

      // Log to console when user logs in
      console.log("User " + username + " logged in");          
    } else {
      // If matching credentials were not found, return code 404 (wrong credentials) to the client
      res.status(404).send()          
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.status(500).send()
  })
})
```